# How to detect is argument jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create function that can be used either with Id or by passing jQuery object.

```
var $myVar = $('#myId');

myFunc($myVar);
myFunc('myId');

function myFunc(value)
{
    // check if value is jQuery or string
}
```

How can I detect what kind of argument was passed to the function?

**Note!** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283255/detect-if-an-argument-is-a-jquery-selector) question is not same. I don't want to pass selector string like `#id.myClass`. I want to pass the jQuery object like in the example.

Comment: A jQuery object is not a "jQuery selector"; it's an object.  A **selector** is a string with CSS selector syntax.

Comment: If you want to detect a jQuery object, then [the part of that post that says `value instanceof of jQuery`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6283431/575527) (le mans: detecting an instance of jQuery object) would be the answer.

Comment: Off the top of my head, just check if the variable is a string or an object?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `typeof` operator

```
if ( typeof value === 'string' ) {
  // it's a string
} else {
  // it's something else
}
```

Or to make really sure it's an instance of the jQuery object

```
if ( typeof value === 'string' ) {
  // it's a string
} else if ( value instanceof $) {
  // it's a jQuery object
} else {
  // something unwanted
}
```

Comment: At least quick tests show that 'value instanceof $' is working smoothly. This was the thing that I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I would promote the second part as that really does the trick excluding other vanilla objects.

Answer (score 3):

Every jquery object has a property `jquery`. This will fail, of course, if your object has `jquery` property...but you can have stricter checking if you want...

```
function(o) {
    if(typeof o == 'object' && o.jquery) // it's jquery object.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunc(value)
{
   if (typeof value == "string") {
      //it's a string
   }
   else if (value != null && typeof value == "object"} {
      //it's an object (presumably jQuery object)
   }
   else {
      //it's null or something else
   }


}
```

Comment: `typeof value` will never be `null`. Did you mean `value != null`?

Comment: @JamesAllardice, yep, that's what I meant. Fixed it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be sufficient to check the type of the argument?

```
function myfunc(arg)
{
    if(typeof arg == 'string')
    {

    }
    else if(typeof arg == 'object')
    {

    }  
}
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AkjzT/).

Comment: This doesn't consider null, which also has typeof = "object".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunc(value)
{
   if(typeof value === 'object') {
   }
   else{
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunc(value)
{
  if(typeof(value) == 'string')
    //this is a string
  else if (value === jQuery)
    //this is jQuery
  else if (typeof(value) == 'object')
    //this is an object
}
```

NOTE: did this in the console:

```
> jQuery
function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
> var value = jQuery
undefined
> value
function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
> value === jQuery
true
```

Comment: value === jQuery gives false for jQuery object

Comment: `value === jQuery` will only be true for jQuery itself, not instances of it. You want the `instanceof` operator. @RGB - Note that `typeof` is an operator, not a function, so you don't need the parentheses (they won't cause any problems, but it can be clearer without them).

Comment: uhh, yes it does.. :P but i see you have a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using typeof, eg:

```
var $myVar = $('#myId');

myFunc($myVar);
myFunc('myId');

function myFunc( value ){
    // check if value is jQuery or string
    switch( typeof value ) {
        case 'object':
        // is object
        break;

        case 'string':
        // is string
        break;

        // etc etc.
    }
}
```